# Not able to check the condition on submit button swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitextfield

Short description :

I am getting one value called `UserValue`. This will come from one response.And i have one `Confirm` button press method. In that each time i need to check whether the user entered amount is greater then `UserValue` amount.

but some time the value will be `UserValue`  will be nill.That time it should not check whethere entered amount in text filed is greater than `UserValue`

Now here my code :

```
 @IBAction func confirmButnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
 print(UserValue)
 let Mvalue = Double((UserValue.formattedAmount()))
                    let stringValue = Int(Mvalue!)

 if doubleValue < stringValue {
      DialogUtils.showMessageWithOk(controller: self, message:  "Maximum Value is : \(UserValue)")

  }
}
```

Its working fine when i got some value in `UserValue` but when i get nill value here its crashing...How can i handle this:

```
let stringValue = Int(Mvalue!)   // crash here
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forcefully unwrapping the `nil`, Due to that its crashing.

Check the `UserValue` is `nil` or not. If not `nil` then do the comparison

```
 @IBAction func confirmButnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
     print(UserValue)

     if let UserValue = UserValue {
       if let Mvalue = Double((UserValue.formattedAmount())) {
          if let stringValue = Int(Mvalue) {
           if doubleValue < stringValue {
               DialogUtils.showMessageWithOk(controller: self, message:  "Maximum Value is : \(UserValue)")
            }
          }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'

Comment: UserValue is optional value right? if not then make it optional

Comment: yes, some time value will come some time vlaue wont come

Comment: I am asking about declaration. not assigning value, Declare like this `UserValue: String?`. And modify `UserValue = (manger.sharedInstance.uservalues)`. Don't unwrap forcefully.

Comment: var UserValue = String()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148294/discussion-between-subramanian-and-hybrid-dev).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of force casting MValue to Int you will get error when MValue is nil or anyother type content except integer

```
 let stringValue = Int(Mvalue!)
```

use like below

```
if let stringValue = Int(Mvalue) {
  //Now it prints your perfect unwrapping value
  if doubleValue < stringValue {
      DialogUtils.showMessageWithOk(controller: self, message:  "Maximum Value   is : \(UserValue)")
  }
}
```